# Mass find and replace unique links - Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I need to replace this whole html that is wrapped in p tags

```
<p class="tumble"><a href='http://www.website.com/autologin.aspx?userid=4JLJufWQ%3d%3d&bookid=87' >
    <img src="http://images.website.com/images/P/image.jpg" alt="cover" /><em>Book</em> - Author</a></p>
```

with

```
<p class="tumble"><embed src="http://daily.website.com/todaybook.aspx" width="258" height="320" /></p>
```

Is there an easy way to do this mass replace. The links and information inside the p tag are different and it would take me weeks to do replace one by one.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `dreamweaver` tag indicates you might be using Dreamweaver. Is that the case?

Comment: yes. sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: @user5248 Is the replacement url always the same? `http://daily.website.com/todaybook.aspx`

Comment: yes always the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to mix string search with a regular expression. [There's a really nice official article breaking this down.](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html)

Your search string will be something like this:

```
<p class="tumble">[^]*</p>
```

Comment: There is one problem with this solution, It does not understand which </p> to end at, so it replaces not just content that is wrapped in inside the "tumble" class p tags, but where the last</p> is in the document. Am I making sense?